# Improvement of a regular expression pattern

Tags: php, html, parsing

I created this script to take informations "at-the-moment" of [this site](http://www.programme-tv.net/programme/toutes-les-chaines/en-ce-moment.html#Grandes%20cha%C3%AEnes):

```
Pictures of name channel
Name of channel
Pictures channel
Times
Title
Type
```

My script (Work):

```
<?php

$url="http://www.programme-tv.net/programme/toutes-les-chaines/en-ce-moment.html#Grandes%20cha%C3%AEnes";
$code_page = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match_all('/<div class="channelItem">(.*?)<img src="(.*?)" alt="Le programme de (.*?)" width="70" height="30">/is', $code_page, $chaines);
preg_match_all('/<div class="show (.*?) at-the-moment current (.*?)">(.*?)<div class="show-infos">(.*?)<\/div>/is', $code_page, $channels);

$i=0;
foreach ($channels as $channel) {
    if($i==3){
        for ($j=0; $j < 38; $j++) {
            preg_match_all('/<span class="(.*?)"><img src="http:\/\/static.programme-tv.net\/var\/epgs\/169\/80x\/(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" width="80" \/><\/span>/', $channel[$j], $image[$j]); 
        }
    }

if($i==4){
        for ($j=0; $j < 38; $j++) { 
            preg_match_all('/<p class="time">(.*?)<\/p>/', $channel[$j], $time[$j]);
            preg_match_all('/<p class="title">(.*?)<\/p>/', $channel[$j], $title[$j]);
            preg_match_all('/<p class="type">(.*?)<\/p>/', $channel[$j], $type[$j]);
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

for ($i=0; $i < 38; $i++) {
    $test = strpos($chaines[2][$i],' </div>');
    if($test != true){
        echo 'Chaines images: <img src="'.$chaines[2][$i].'"/><br />';
        echo 'Chaines: '.$chaines[3][$i].'<br />';
        echo 'image : <img src="http://static.programme-tv.net/var/epgs/169/80x/'.$image[$i][2][0].'" /><br />'; 
        echo 'Temps : '.trim($time[$i][1][0]).'<br />';
        echo 'Titre : '.substr($title[$i][1][0], strpos($title[$i][1][0], '>') + 1, strrpos($title[$i][1][0], '<')).'<br />';
        echo 'Type : '.$type[$i][1][0].'<br />';
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
?>
```

I would like to improve and find a better regular expression pattern because I use 6 regular expression pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by "pattern"? I assume you mean regular expression pattern? Additionally, you say that you're using 4 but I can see 6.

Comment: Oops yes it's 6 ^^ sorry. And yes I mean "regular expression pattern".

Comment: Please read: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) - consider asking a follow-on question. Your edits herehave been rolled back

Answer (score 5):

To be honest I don't think your current way of handling is 'clean'.
But I would suggest you to use a HTML DOM parser. I took the liberty to google it for you and http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ seems quite what you need.

It's a PHP HTML parser, which allows you to write

```
// Find all element which class=foo
$ret = $html->find('.at-the-moment');
```

instead of

```
preg_match_all('/<div class="show (.*?) at-the-moment current (.*?)">(.*?)<div class="show-infos">(.*?)<\/div>/is', $code_page, $channels);
```

Also your other regexes can be switched (read the documentation)

To be honest, I never used this library before, but I've worked with beautifulsoup which is a Python equivalent, which would do the trick for you perfectly.
(source: http://www.givegoodweb.com/post/210/html-parser-for-php)

Wishing you the best!

Comment: +1, [Don't parse HTML with Regular expressions!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1310566)

Comment: Thank you.

I try to use DOMDocument at the moment. And later your HTML DOM parser for watch the difference. 

In what conditions does one uses regular expressions?

Comment: This is a hard question. Regular Expressions can do awesome things in just a blink of a second, however they are hard to maintain and to check all possible scenario's. A beter question is to ask 'when shouldn't you use them?' -> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions
As you can see 'parsing HTML with regexp' is mentioned as first ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't parse HTML with regular expressions

First of all, [don't parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Second of all, [don't parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

#### Indentation

Pay attention to correct indentation, for example in this code:

> ```
> foreach ($channels as $channel) {
>     if($i==3){
>         // ...
>     }
>
> if($i==4){
> ```

The indent level if this last `if` statement is unexpected.
It gives the impression that it's outside of the `foreach` loop,
but no it's still inside. Be careful,
this kind of thing can seriously hurt readability.

#### Using an alternative pattern separator instead of `///`

You could simplify many of your patterns by using a different separator instead of `/`, for example `|`:

```
preg_match_all('|<span class="(.*?)"><img src="http://static.programme-tv.net/var/epgs/169/80x/(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" width="80" /></span>|', $channel[$j], $image[$j]);
```

This way you don't need to escape so many embedded `/`, which is a lot easier on the eyes too.

#### Readability

I recommend to borrow from the formatting conventions of other languages and put spaces around operators and parentheses. Instead of this:

> ```
> if($i==4){
> ```

Write like this:

```
if ($i == 4) {
```

#### Conditions on boolean expressions

When working with boolean values, you don't need the `==` or `!=` operators,
you can use the boolean values directly. Instead of this:

> ```
> if($test != true){
> ```

You can write simply:

```
if (!$test) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the constructive comments and for the tips. I did not know for the patterns. 

I have my script properly indent but on this forum the indent have changed :(

Answer (score 0):

Script with DOMDocument :

```
<?php

    $url="http://www.programme-tv.net/programme/en-ce-moment.html#TNT%20-%20Cha%C3%AEnes%20Gratuites";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $classname = 'at-the-moment';
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $datas = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $tags = $data->getElementsByTagName('img');
        if($tags->length === 1){
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $infos['image_en_cours'][] = $tag->getAttribute('src');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $infos['image_en_cours'][] = 'no_image';
        }

        $xml = $data->ownerDocument->saveXML($data);
        $dom->loadHTML($xml);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

        $classname = 'title';
        $titles = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
        foreach ($titles as $title) {
            $infos['titre'][] = $title->nodeValue;
        }

        $classname = 'time';
        $times = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
        foreach ($times as $time) {
            $infos['temps'][] = $time->nodeValue;
        }

        $classname = 'type';
        $types = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            $infos['types'][] = $type->nodeValue;
        }
    }

    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $classname = 'channel_logo';
    $channels = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

    foreach ($channels as $channel) {
        $datas = $channel->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($datas as $data) {
            $infos['image_nom_television'][] = $data->getAttribute('src');
            $infos['nom_chaine'][] = substr($data->getAttribute('alt'), 16);
        }
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < 38; $i++) { 
        echo 'Image de la chaine : <img src="'.$infos['image_nom_television'][$i].'" alt="'.$infos['nom_chaine'][$i].'" /><br />';
        echo 'Nom de la chaine : '.$infos['nom_chaine'][$i].'<br />';
        echo utf8_decode('Image en cours : <img src="'.$infos['image_en_cours'][$i].'" alt="'.$infos['titre'][$i].'" /><br />');
        echo utf8_decode('Titre : '.$infos['titre'][$i].'<br />');
        echo 'Commencé à : '.$infos['temps'][$i].'<br />';
        echo utf8_decode('Genre : '.$infos['types'][$i].'<br />');
        echo '<hr>';
    }

?>
```

I think this script is better than the first. What do you think ? you see an optimization ?